# Is WDK for Windows 10 compatible with the C++17 language standard?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wdk

Is WDK for Windwos 10 compatible with the C++17 language standard ?

I am asking because, after I switched the compiler form C++14 to the C++17 language standard
( with the WDK v10.0.19041.0 included ), I started to receive the following warning:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\crt\setjmp.h(206,107): warning C5040: dynamic exception specifications are valid only in C++14 and earlier; treating as noexcept(false)`

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-by-compiler-version?view=msvc-170) the `C5040` warning was added in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 (compiler version 19.12.25830.0).

Below is the offending code:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#if _MSC_VER >= 1200
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4987) /* nonstandard extension: throw (...) */
#endif
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl longjmp(_In_reads_(_JBLEN) jmp_buf _Buf, _In_ int _Value) throw(...);
#if _MSC_VER >= 1200
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
}
#else
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl longjmp(_In_reads_(_JBLEN) jmp_buf _Buf, _In_ int _Value);
#endif
```

**Note** that this is a code in the Microsoft's WDK that generates this warning - not my code.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\crt\setjmp.h(206,107)`

Apparently, the [throw specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Someone has already complained to Microsoft about this 5 years ago (in May 2018) but nothing was done about it.  See [this bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/wdk-setjmp-compilation-error-in-c17/247882).

Comment: The [throw specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) was removed in C++17, so I guess the answer is "no". However, the latest version of the WDK appears to be 10.0.22621.382.

Comment: Thank you.  I edited my question to make it clear that I am referring to a WDK for Windows 10.

Comment: @Nelfeal Specific WDK versions only work on specific windows version, the latest version is for Windows 11 only

Comment: I figured. Then, if by "compatible" you mean "compliant", the answer is a clear no. However, it can very well be compatible with the MSVC compiler, since it and the WDK are Microsoft products...

Comment: There is very little incentive to fix this header.  If it helps decide a programmer to use C instead of C++ to develop their driver then they'd consider that a win.  And it is trivial to turn off the warning.

Comment: Are you calling this function directly?  Or through some other function?

Comment: I am not calling the `longjmp` function directly.  Maybe some other function calls it or maybe it is not called at all by anything.  Only the WDK is included into the project and the compiler parses the offending code.